# Find operation on two matrices from given scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22} \end{bmatrix}$, what operation on matrices will result in the scalar $$-a_{11} b_{22} - a_{22} b_{11} + a_{12} b_{12} + a_{21} b_{21}$$ ?

Note: I stumbled upon this question while trying to find eigenvalues of a transfer matrix in physics. I really wasn't sure what the answer should be but was mainly looking for a way to compactify notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you have can be expressed in terms of determinants:
$$-a_{11} b_{22} - a_{22}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{12} + a_{21}b_{21} = \det(A)+\det(B)-\det(A^\color{red}{T}+B)$$

For completeness, following is a similar expression you might find useful:
$$-a_{11} b_{22} - a_{22}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{\color{red}{21}} + a_{21}b_{\color{red}{12}} = \det(A)+\det(B)-\det(A+B)$$

Comment: That's a nice formula, it gives you a handy way to compute the determinant of a sum of two 2x2 matrices.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\text{vec}(A)^T\pmatrix{0&0&0&-1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\-1&0&0&0}\text{vec}(B),
$$
where $\text{vec}(X)$ represents the vector you get, when you stack the columns of $X$ on top of each other.